# SSIS Package Error After Updating to VS2019

Tags: xml, ssis, etl, integration

After updating to VS2019 I have been receiving the following build error in an SSIS package.

'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsGenericException: Failed to load XML due to error 0xC00CE504 "A name was started with an invalid character. Line 14, Column 1"'.

I have looked through the XML for the package and line 14 is the build version and I don't see where an invalid character would be.  I can still load the same project in VS2015 and execute as expected.  I have stared at this for quite some time trying to find where the error might be.  Has anyone else experienced this?

I am running Visual Studio version 16.11.11 with SSIS designer version 15.0.2000.180. SSIS Project Extension version 3.16.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
   DTS:refId="Package"
   DTS:CreationDate="9/4/2020 8:48:51 AM"
   DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
   DTS:CreatorComputerName="STEVE-SALOWIT"
   DTS:CreatorName="MORLEY\ssalowitz"
   DTS:DTSID="{5F2F7616-8292-449F-AE0E-ACAEBDA52423}"
   DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
   DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.2000.180"
   DTS:LocaleID="1033"
   DTS:ObjectName="ESG Workday_Report_Import"
   DTS:PackageType="5"
   DTS:VersionBuild="278"
   DTS:VersionGUID="{5B1F0D3E-1A82-48BA-A786-6FD0822E7871}">
   <DTS:Property
     DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
```

Comment: Please add to your question the following:

(1) VS2019 version.

(2) SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension version.

Comment: I'm going to go with that's a spurious error. Is this an SSIS Project deployment model (2012+) or the legacy Package deployment model (2005+). If you copy the existing 2015 based solution to a new folder and open that again, examine the SSIS upgrade wizard (I think that runs) in case it had reported an error. Otherwise, look at your 2015 package and identify whether there are custom components (CozyRoc, Kingswaysoft) involved as they could be pooching things

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have updated the post with the version info

Comment: @billinkc this is in the project deployment model.  I copied the solution to the a new folder and opened it but an upgrade wizard did not run and I still get the same error.  This package is pretty straightforward.  It contains a script task that connects to an API to download a .csv then imports said data to a db. Nothing custom that would be messing it up